# How to display Previous month total dates in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to display Previous month dates.May i know the query which is used to display all dates

Expected Output:

Current date = '2012-09-13'
I want to display my result as

```
1
2
3
4
,
,
,
,
31
```

these dates should come from month 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
;WITH DATES (date)
AS(
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, dateadd(month,-1,getdate())), 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,date)
FROM DATES
WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,date)<=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)-1
)SELECT DAY(date) AS DAYS FROM DATES
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT NUMBER  
FROM   MASTER..SPT_VALUES 
WHERE  TYPE='P'
AND    NUMBER BETWEEN 
       DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1,0))
AND    DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()),-1))
```

Replcae Getdate() with your date